# Looping input function

Tags: c++, curses

Currently, I have a function that loops to gather input for program execution, but I feel that it is a bit lacking, overthought and unoptimized. I would love any input on the **process**, **coding style**, or **usability** of the function.

I feel like the use of `while (true)` is not really optimized here.

My code uses [`curses`](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/) and `unistd.h`.

```
// Heart of the display of the program
void startEvolutionLoop (Grid* grid, size_t speed) {
    clear();

    // Infinitely loops until 'q' is pressed
    while (true) {
        // First of all displays the grid with supporting information
        displayGrid(grid);
        printw("[Space] Evolve once        [Enter] Run evolutions        [q] Exit\n");

        // Gets the most recently touched character
        int c = getch();

        //  - if space (' ') evolves and loops again
        //  - if ('q') ends the loops
        //  - if enter ('\n') starts a sub-loop similar to the main one, but waits for any character to stop
        if (c == ' ') {
            grid->evolve();
        } else if (c == 'q') {
            return;
        } else if (c == '\n') {
            nodelay(stdscr, TRUE); // Getting of the input is asyncronous
            // Infinitely loops until any key is pressed
            while (true) {
                grid->evolve();
                displayGrid(grid);

                printw("Press any key to end execution...                       \n"); // Extra whitespace to override previously written stuff in this area

                // If there has been something inputted, then break out of this sub-loop
                if (getch() != ERR) {
                    break;
                }

                usleep((__useconds_t)speed * 1000); // Sleep the desired amount of time (in micro seconds converted to milliseconds)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For context (which is not necessary), you can check out my [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/Wintro/game-of-life).

Comment: What exactly do you want to optimize in the loop, speed or memory usage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider following the [Single Responsibility Principal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and break the function up into smaller functions that do less.

Note: This answer makes use of the loopEvos() that is provided in the updated version of the source files on GitHub.

```
void loopEvos (Grid* grid, size_t speed) {
    nodelay(stdscr, TRUE); // Getting of the input is asyncronous
    // Infinitely loops until any key is pressed
    while (true) {
        grid->evolve();
        displayGrid(grid);

        printw("Press any key to end execution...\n");

        // If there has been something inputted, then break out of this sub-loop
        if (getch() != ERR) {
            break;
        }

        usleep((__useconds_t)speed * 1000); // Sleep the desired amount of time (in micro seconds converted to milliseconds)
    }
}
```

Whenever code is written future expansion of the program/function must be considered. In the function above there is the code :

```
        if (c == ' ') {
            grid->evolve();
        } else if (c == 'q') {
            return;
        } else if (c == '\n') {
            loopEvos(grid, speed);
            nodelay(stdscr, FALSE);
        }
```

It would be is easier to expand the code if another type of control statement was used instead. If the code was

```
        switch (c) {
            case ' ':
                grid->evolve();
                continue;
            case 'q':
                return;
            case '\n':
                loopEvos(grid, speed);
                nodelay(stdscr, FALSE);
                continue:
            default :
                printw("Invalid character input\n");
                return;
        }
```

It would be easier to handle any additional input characters such as 
`KEY_UP`, `KEY_LEFT`, `KEY_DOWN` and `KEY_UP`.

```
        switch (c) {
            case ' ':
                grid->evolve();
                continue;
            case 'q':
                return;
            case '\n':
                loopEvos(grid, speed);
                nodelay(stdscr, FALSE);
                continue;
        // The following code is modified from procs/procs.hpp in the GitHub account.
            case 's':
                askFileSave(grid);
                continue;
            case 'c':
                changeSettings(&speed);
                continue;
            case KEY_UP:
                if (cursorPosY >= 1) {
                    cursorPosY -= 1;
                }
                continue;
            case KEY_LEFT:
                if (cursorPosX >= 2) {
                    cursorPosX -= 2;
                }
                continue;
            case KEY_DOWN:
                if (cursorPosY < (grid->y - 1)) {
                    cursorPosY += 1;
                }
                continue;
            case KEY_RIGHT:
                if ((cursorPosX / 2) < grid->x - 1) {
                    cursorPosX += 2;
                }
                continue;
            default :
                printw("Invalid character input\n");
                return;
        }
```

It might be easier to read, understand and modify the outer loop if it was a do
while loop rather than a while true loop

```
void startEvolutionLoop (Grid* grid, size_t speed) {
    clear();

     int userInput;
     do {
         // First of all displays the grid with supporting information
         displayGrid(grid);
         printw("[Space] Evolve once        [Enter] Run evolutions        [q] Exit\n");

         // Gets the most recently touched character
         userInput = getch();

         if (userInput == ' ') {
             grid->evolve();
         } else if (userInput == 'q') {
             continue;
         } else if (userInput == '\n') {
             loopEvos(grid, speed);  // from procs/procs.hpp in the GitHub account.
             nodelay(stdscr, FALSE);
         }
     } while (userInput != `q`);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! The project was mostly a learning demo, but I'll be sure to take your notes into consideration for the future.